# Уточнение и ИЛИ

Tags: уточнения, или

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться в предложении.

Вопрос заключается в следующем.
Есть обозначение транспортного средства, где перечисляются виды цистерн, а в конце предложения стоит фраза, -- "или МЭГК индивидуальной вместимостью 3м³"
Как по правилам, можно трактовать фразу после слова **или** применительно ко всем ранее перечисленным цистернам или это может быть применено только к МЭГК?

Фраза полностью:

> Применено выражение индивидуальной вместимости 3м³.транспортное
> средство, кроме транспортного средства EX/III, FL или OX или MEMU,
> предназначенное для перевозки опасных грузов во встроенных цистернах
> или съёмных цистернах вместимостью более 1 м³ либо в
> контейнерах-цистернах, переносных цистернах или МЭГК индивидуальной
> вместимостью более 3 м³

Comment: Кирилл, не фраза, а какая-то терминологическая шизофазия)

Comment: "Применено выражение индивидуальной вместимости 3м³.транспортное"  - не понятно, что это за точка, после которой идет слово начинающееся с маленькой буквы.
"..транспортное средство (кроме транспортного средства EX/III, FL или OX или MEMU), предназначенное(по всё видимости "транспортное средство в начале) ..."
Далее ... "предназначенное для перевозки опасных грузов : во встроенных цистернах или съёмных цистернах вместимостью более 1 м³; либо в контейнерах-цистернах, переносных цистернах или МЭГК индивидуальной вместимостью более 3 м³."